# rxgraph giving index out of range when turtlebot node starts

Tags: ros, rxgraph, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get a graph of what is running on my turtlebot but when I start rxgraph after the turtlebot_bringup.launch it stops and says there is an index out of range error.  Here is the output from the terminal where I ran rxgraph:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/rx/rxgraph/src/rxgraph/impl.py", line 123, in run
    changed = g.update()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/impl/graph.py", line 568, in update
        updated = self._node_refresh(next) or updated
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/impl/graph.py", line 452, in _node_refresh
    updated = self._node_refresh_businfo(node, api, bad_node)
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/impl/graph.py", line 407, in _node_refresh_businfo
    connection_id = info[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

As a final note, rxgraph runs fine with other applications but with the turtlebot_bringup.launch it produces the above.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11091/rxgraph-giving-index-out-of-range-when-turtlebot-node-starts/) by [jbeck27](https://answers.ros.org/users/862/jbeck27/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-09-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a known bug in rxgraph ticketed here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3579

you can use rosnode list to see the list of node running on your TurtleBot

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-09-01**:
now that electric is out, we will try and turning the wheels for 1.4.8 (maybe release next week)

**Comment by [jbeck27](https://answers.ros.org/users/862/jbeck27/) on 2011-09-01**:
Is there any idea on release date for 1.4.8?  Thanks for the quick response as well.